# Any way to install NetBeans without language support?

Tags: netbeans

I'm installing Netbeans 8.2 and it is taking a long time (15+ minutes) just to unpack the modules, many of which are support for Brazilian Portuguese, Russian, or Chinese. Is there any way to disable these? I don't speak any of those languages + no one else will be using my PC.

Comment: I don't think there is a customising option while installing; but still, which platform are you installing it in?

Comment: Windows 10 (x64)

Comment: This is kind of a moot point for me now; the install has completed. But maybe someone might want to know how to do this in the future.

Comment: From my past experience and search over the Internet, I'm almost quite sure that customisation of locale-specific modules is not available while installation. It is just that there is no point writing a useless answer for it